# What is the correct symbol for writing the deviation between measurements?

Tags: notation

I have multiple measurements and I want to indicate that the difference between the lowest deviation and the highest deviation is between a number and another number. For example, when calculating the voltages and comparing it with the experimental data, I get a difference from 0.1V to 15V in a interval of many measurements. Basically, the lowest deviation is 0.1 and the highest is 15, following some tens of experiments.

I am thinking to use $\Delta V = 0.1-15V$. But is this a correct notation? Or so to say, is this a standard notation? It looks like a subtraction, rather than an interval. Which is the correct notation?

I have seen notations such as: $\Delta V = 0.1 \div 15 V$ or $\Delta V = 0.1 ... 15V$ or $\Delta V = 0.1,0.15$ and, of course the traditional between $\Delta V = 0.1V$ and $\Delta V=15V$.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: To be honest, I would write down the results in a table with the deviations written down for each measurement. If you refer to the deviations, I'd then use something like "...with deviations between $\Delta V = 0.1 \mathrm{V}$ and $\Delta V = 15 \mathrm{V}$". Also, I would avoid using $V$ for the quantity **and** the unit you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's how I have it now, but I need to put that in an abstract which has a limited number of characters and that's why I want to use a shorter notation.

Comment: Well you could use $0.1 V \leq \Delta V \leq 15 V$.

Comment: I didn't think about that, but it looks just right. How would you formulate it? "A deviation of $0.1V \leq \Delta V \leq 15V$ was found"?  Would this make sense?

Comment: Personally, I avoid as much "math environments" (in the LaTeX sense of the word) in an abstract, and thus would use "A deviation between $0.1 V$ and $15V$ was found." If you're *really* tight on space, I'd write "A deviation $0.1 V \leq \Delta V \leq 15V$ was found." 
Although there doesn't seem to be much of a difference here...

Comment: Thank you, John! I will use "A deviation between 0.1V and 15V was found" for now.

Answer (score 2):

A very popular non symbolic notation in electrical datasheets for most quantities having some specified range is the standard:

$$\begin{align}\Delta V_\textrm{min}&=0.1~\textrm V\\\Delta V_\textrm{max} &=15~\textrm V\end{align}$$

And you can extend it to present another information, operators or conditions:

$$\begin{align}\Delta V_\textrm{avg} &=0.5~\textrm V \\ \Delta V_\textrm{typical} &=0.55~\textrm V\end{align}$$

This don't need to be in a subscript shape:
$$\Delta V (50~\textrm{Hz},~ 20~^\circ \textrm C)=15~\textrm V$$

The last case sometimes is represented with a "@":
$$\Delta V @~ 30~\textrm{mA},~~20\text{VAC}=11~\textrm V$$

Hence you don't have to put operators between the figures, and you preserve a more database friendly representation.